# How can I '\input' a file without getting the implicit newline?

Tags: external-files, input

### Intro

I'm working on a lightweight package that allows you to put any content (typically LaTeX code) in an environment, then use that content multiple times, each time scanned separately, so you can use it both as verbatim output and interpreted as LaTeX.

Its main purpose is to typeset LaTeX code and its 'result' side-by-side; useful for documenting TeX packages without having to copy/paste code. But it has other purposes as well.

After experimenting with `\scantokens` until I gave up in tears, I arrived at the `filecontents` environment, which almost solved my problem singlehandedly!

### The Problem

The problem is, when reintroducing `filecontent`ed code through `\input`, LaTeX adds an implicit newline at the end, which translates to whitespace that I can't seem to get rid of.

I've seen many semi-related questions floating around, with answers employing techniques like:

- reading a file line-by-line,
- using `\everyeof` in some clever way,
- playing with `\endlinechar` or
- using packages such as `catchfile`

but none of them provides a clear answer to the following question:

### The Question

How can I `\input` a file without getting the implicit newline?

### Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{tmp.tex}
    \LaTeX{}\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \fbox{\input{tmp.tex}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the extra whitespace to the right of the box.

Note also that I'm definitely not adding any explicit whitespace. Even a manually produced file (so, not using `filecontents`) with no newlines at all exhibits the same problem.

Comment: Could you show us and example you've put together that illustrates the basic idea of what you're aiming for?  And then point out how the example isn't fully realizing you ideal result.

Comment: @A.Ellett Done.

Comment: In this context the final empty line is *not* responsible for that space: `\par` does nothing in restricted horizontal mode.

Comment: @egreg This is not about `\par`, but about the single newline (`\n` if you will) that TeX adds to my input. It gets converted to a space, just like TeX always does with single newlines. No?

Comment: @mhelvens No: it's an empty line, so it gets converted to `\par`

Comment: @mhelvens Try `abc\input{tmp}def` and you'll see the `\par` in action.

Comment: @egreg I tried just that, and it is converted to a space, not a paragraph. `abcCONTENT def`. Unless your tmp-file has, itself, an empty line.

Comment: @mhelvens I believe that we're discussing different issues. But the space you see is *simply* the end of line of the last (or unique) line.

Comment: @egreg I'm talking about the visible space after `\LaTeX`. See my own answer to see a version *without* the space. Indeed, it's 'simply' the end-of-line. My question is how to... get rid of it. :-)

Comment: @mhelvens Append `\empty` after the last token in the last line

Comment: @mhelvens The space comes from the line ending of the last line. It disappears if the last line ends with a comment character or with a macro name (try with `\LaTeX` or even `\LaTeX ` rather than `\LaTeX{}`.) Had you used repeated `\read` you would have indeed gotten a final `\par`. With `\input` it is not a problem of an implicit newline. Of course, this doesn't answer your question about getting rid of this space...

Comment: @egreg For the purpose of this question, I cannot change the content of the file. <>---<> @jfbu I don't know about repeated `read` (never tried it). Yes, ending the last line with a comment char or a macro that gobbles space removes the visible space. That's why I used `{}` in the example. :-) But that doesn't imply an empty line to me, but simply a single eol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following requires a different command, say `\minput`:

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\newcommand\minput[1]{%
  \input{#1}%
  \ifhmode\ifnum\lastnodetype=11 \unskip\fi\fi}

\begin{filecontents*}{tmp.tex}
\LaTeX{}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{tmp2.tex}
\LaTeX
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{tmp3.tex}
\LaTeX\hspace{2em}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\input{tmp.tex}} \fbox{\minput{tmp.tex}}

\minput{tmp}Nospace \minput{tmp} Space

\minput{tmp2} Space

\minput{tmp3}Nospace

\LaTeX\hspace{2em}Nospace
\end{document}
```

This will fail if the input file ends with something like `\hskip 2pt`, but I believe one can ignore such cases.

[image]

Comment: Looking good! I guess this is the closest we are likely to come to a correct answer. :-)

Comment: Ah, in naming the command for my package, can you tell me what the 'm' stands for? I'll use it if it makes sense. ;-)

Comment: Also, if you have some time, could you write a paragraph about the limitations of this solution to include in the docs? I'll quote you by name.

Comment: @mhelvens The limitation is that an explicit horizontal glue specification at the end of the input file will be lost. Not if the specification uses `\hspace`, but only with `\hskip`. It will not work if one fiddles with `\endlinechar`, but I guess it won't be the case with your setting.

Answer (score 6):

try adding `\endinput` as the last line of the file to be `\input`.  this will cause anything that follows to be ignored.  in fact, you can add anything you want following `\endinput`, which makes it useful for including notes to yourself.

it's also probably a good idea to end the last "real" line of your file with a `%` to avoid even that newline.

`\endinput` is a tex primitive, and often isn't mentioned in latex manuals.

Comment: Very useful! But not exactly what I'm looking for. Why? Because I want to be able to 'retrieve' the content of that file in multiple ways, not just a simple `\input`. While your suggestion solves my immediate problem, it would cause unwanted output when the user of my package tries to typeset the content of the file with `listings`, for example. So for the purpose of this question, I cannot change the content of the file.

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to get a satisfactory behavior by directly following the `\input` directive with `\unskip`.

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{tmp.tex}
    \LaTeX{}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \fbox{\input{tmp.tex}}
    \fbox{\input{tmp.tex}\unskip}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is not a valid answer to the question, since I now no longer have the option of putting whitespace at the end *if I want to*. But it's better than nothing.

Comment: You can protect desired whitespace by putting some item after it that, although invisible, is not a skip and therefore makes the "last skip" null.  Both `\special{}` and `\penalty0` work, as would `\hbox{}`.

Comment: @RyanReich Unfortunately, any such addition solution would require me to pollute the input file (which is not under my control).

Comment: *Do* you want whitespace at the end, sometimes?

Comment: @RyanReich Ideally, I would faithfully return whatever the user types in my environment (the one I'm developing). What if I wanted to use my environment to demonstrate this exact problem?

Comment: I always hate to accept my own answer over the answers of others, but in this case using `\unskip` has been the only solution that gave me an acceptable result. However, if anyone can show me a way that faithfully preserves the exact content of the environment (including whitespace, or lack thereof), I'd happily give them the points.

Answer (score 3):

Using `\everyeof` is too late to gobble the space. One can set `\endlinechar=\m@ne` (i.e. set it to -1), but this will ignore all end-of-lines, not just the trailing space-causing one.

One might consider reading the file into a macro where the trailing space can be controlled more easily. However, any solution involving storing the file contents in a macro will suffer from the problem that the file itself cannot initiate catcode changes.

Possible solutions (with the above caveats) are presented with, and without, the `catchfile` package:

- **Without** the `catchfile` package, it is easier to gobble that space early. This is adapted from code on a [comp.text.tex thread](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/854391a7654a467d/6825ae391f0a7bab); I have added a space to the parameter text of `\@inputfiledef` to gobble it. Note the restrictions of this approach as discussed there. In particular, the file should not contain `\ENDMARKER`.

  ```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents*}{tmp.tex}
        \LaTeX{}

        and some more text \LaTeX{}\end{filecontents*}

    \makeatletter
    \long\def\@inputfiledef#1#2 \ENDMARKER{%<-- added a space here
      \endgroup
      \def#1{#2}%
      \noexpand
    }%
    \long\def\inputfiledef#1#2{%
      \begingroup
      \everyeof{\ENDMARKER}%
      \expandafter\@inputfiledef\expandafter#1#2%
    }%
    \newcommand*{\myinputnospace}[1]{\inputfiledef\myfile{\@@input #1\space}\relax\myfile}
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
        % hopefully doesn't end with a space
        \fbox{\myinputnospace{tmp.tex}}

        % illustrate that the line endings are being read (not the case if \endlinechar=\m@ne)
        \myinputnospace{tmp.tex}
        %\show\myfile
    \end{document}
  ```
- The `catchfile` package does some magic to use a less likely `\ENDMARKER`, but this makes it harder for me to see how to extend it to gobble the space, but one can always strip the space from the macro afterwards, as I have done here:

  ```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{filecontents*}{tmp.tex}
        \LaTeX{}

        and some more text \LaTeX{}\end{filecontents*}

    \usepackage{catchfile}
    \usepackage{trimspaces}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\myinputnospace}[1]{%
        \CatchFileDef{\myfile}{#1}{}%
        \trim@post@space@in\myfile
        % could also consider trimming a \par from the end if necessary
        \myfile
    }
    \makeatother

    \begin{document}
        % hopefully doesn't end with a space
        \fbox{\myinputnospace{tmp.tex}}

        % illustrate that the line endings are being read (not the case if \endlinechar=\m@ne)
        \myinputnospace{tmp.tex}
        %\show\myfile
    \end{document}
  ```

Comment: I've taken a look at `catchfile` before. But I'm still not sure what they add over a simple `\def\cmd{\input{file.tex}}`. I believe they perform some catcode preparations, but I should note that I want the file content to be scanned within the current catcode regime.

Comment: With your command, the contents of the file are not saved in the macro, only the `\input` command. It is difficult to use `\edef`, `\expandafter` and `\@@input` to do it without issues. As far as I understand, it's up to the user to specify any desired catcode changes in the third argument 'setup' to `\CatchFileDef`. I left this argument blank to mean use the current regime. But any solution involving storing the file contents in a macro will suffer from the problem that the file itself cannot initiate catcode changes.

Comment: Some very good points! Especially that last point, which kind of prevents me from using the `catchfile` solution by default. Nonetheless, I could perhaps offer it as an option.

Comment: @cyberSingularity You could wrap up this in the definition of a command.

Comment: @mhelvens: If I understand it correctly, another upshot of that thread I've linked to appears to be that, unless capturing the file in a command, it is not possible to remove the EOF 'token' before it is too late (where by 'too late', I mean resorting to something like `\unskip`), unless perhaps you are able to introduce a new engine primitive...

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just say `\endlinechar=-1` instead of `\endlinechar=\m@one`, which is not defined by the LaTeX kernel and it's not clear (to me) where it originates from?

Comment: @Witiko: a rather belated update, but yes it would and sorry for the typo; now amended.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not the implicit newline at the end, but the *explicit* newline.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
  \begin{filecontents*}{file.tex}
    xyz%
  \end{filecontents*}
  \begin{filecontents*}{file2.tex}
    xyz
  \end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
  \fbox{\input{file.tex}}
  \fbox{\input{file2.tex}}
\end{document}
```

The first one has no space, the second one does.

Also, note the `filecontents` package, which makes using and reusing a document with this environment more convenient.

Comment: Hm... I do still believe that it's the *implicit* newline you're escaping there with the `%` char. Just create a file manually with no newlines at all and try to input that one. <>---<> Anyway, your solution would be similar to the one suggested by barbara beeton, which requires me to change the file. For the purpose of this question, I cannot change the file.

Comment: @mhelvens Ryan is right. The implicit empty line has no effect in this context, because you're building an `\hbox` and `\par` does nothing in restricted horizontal mode.

Comment: @RyanReich Did you actually test your code there, with `xyz\end{filecontents*}`? Because for me it still generates a space.

Comment: @RyanReich Strange. Then we may be using a different version of... something? "pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)" and "filecontents 2011/10/08 v1.3" here.

Comment: @mhelvens: never mind, it does produce a space.  I had made a change elsewhere that canceled it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using `\lstinputlisting` (from the `listings` package) or `\VerbatimInput` from the `fancyvrb` package?  They both give you powerful ways of reading in files and formatting them as desired.

Comment: That is indeed a good way to *typeset* LaTeX code from a file. But in this case I'm looking for a way to actually *interpret* the LaTeX code (without the annoying endline there).