# \input produces errors, copy&paste not

Tags: listings, input

I'm working currently on a beamer-document and want to use LaTeX-code. Therefore I set up the listings-package in the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{keywordcolor}{HTML}{102D5D}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,.6,0}
\definecolor{commentcolor}{HTML}{562B71}
\lstset{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    texcsstyle=*\bf\color{keywordcolor},
    numbers=left,
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{darkgreen},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{commentcolor},
    morekeywords={},
    otherkeywords={$, \{, \}, \[, \]},
    tabsize=2,
    frame=leftline,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \begin{lstlisting}
    \usepackage[Option]{Paket}
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The tex-file `otherkeywords` contains `{$, \{, \}, \[, \]}`. If I use `\input`, I'll get a bunch of errors. If I use the content for itself, I'll get the right result. Am I doing something wrong?

The errors:

```
Improper alphabetic constant backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}}
Extra \else backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}}
Improper alphabetic constant backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}}
Improper alphabetic constant backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}}
Paragraph ended before \filehook@@ensureext was complete
Missing \endcsname inserted
```

I tried all the suggestions at [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86248/how-can-i-input-a-file-without-getting-the-implicit-newline), but no success for me.

Sincerely

Comment: Tell as what type of errors those are. Also an MWE would be nice, that reproduces those errors.

Comment: You can't use `\input` there.

Comment: `otherkeywords` wants a list of (possibly escaped) characters, not the instructions to produce a list of characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file `otherkeywords.tex` contains the value of key `otherkeywords`, then the value can given as macro in this case. Package `catchfile` helps in storing the contents of a file in a macro:

```
\usepackage{catchfile}
\CatchFileDef{\otherkeywords}{otherkeywords}{\endlinechar=-1\relax}
\lstset{
    % ...,
    otherkeywords=\otherkeywords,
    % ...,
}
```

`\input` can not be used here, because it is not expandable and it should produce the list with *one* expansion step. But `\input` can be used with `\lstset`:

```
% otherkeywords-alternative.tex
\lstset{otherkeywords={$, \{, \}, \[, \]}}
```

and in the main file:

```
\lstset{%
  % old entries without otherkeywords
}
\input{otherkeywords-alternative}
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation of Heiko's answer, with a new key:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\definecolor{keywordcolor}{HTML}{102D5D}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,.6,0}
\definecolor{commentcolor}{HTML}{562B71}

\makeatletter
\lst@Key{otherkeywordsfile}{}{%
  \let\lst@otherkeywords\@empty
  \let\lst@temp\@empty
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \CatchFileDef{\lst@temp}{#1}{\endlinechar=\m@ne}%
  \fi
  \expandafter\lst@for\expandafter{\lst@temp}\do{%
    \lst@MakeActive{##1}%
    \lst@lExtend\lst@otherkeywords{%
      \expandafter\lst@CArg\lst@temp\relax\lst@CDef
        {}\lst@PrintOtherKeyword\@empty}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\lstset{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    texcsstyle=*\bfseries\color{keywordcolor},
    numbers=left,
    breaklines=true,
    keywordstyle=\color{darkgreen},
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{commentcolor},
    morekeywords={},
%    otherkeywords={$, \{, \}, \[, \]},
    otherkeywordsfile=otherkeywords, % <---- the value is the file name
    tabsize=2,
    frame=leftline,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

    \begin{lstlisting}
    \usepackage[Option]{Paket}
    \end{lstlisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the `otherkeywords.tex` file the braces can be omitted, so it can be

```
$, \{, \}, \[, \]
```

A similar idea could be used for `morekeywords`.