# Use \input with siunitx's \num

Tags: siunitx, word-count

In my implementation of an automatic word count (adapted from this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117532/40803)), only the count and nothing else is output to a text file, to be inserted into the tex document with `\input`. This works fine, but not when combined with siunitx's `\num` for number formatting, which  produces an error. The problem is likely the newline character that `\input` automatically added. My attempt to circumvent the newline with this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87202/40803) doesn't help. How can I make this work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[group-minimum-digits=4,group-separator={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_wordcount.txt}
1234
\end{filecontents*}
  
\newcommand\minput[1]{% doesn't help
  \input{#1}%
  \ifhmode\ifnum\lastnodetype=11 \unskip\fi\fi}

\begin{document}

\input{\jobname_wordcount.txt}words % works
% \num\input{\jobname_wordcount.txt}words % causes error

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another expansion problem (`\input` is not expandable). Usually there would be a `functional` answer, but it doesn't seem to support optional argument yet.

Comment: @user202729 Optional argument is in my todo list. I will add an answer after optional argument is supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead load the file's content in a token list and use that as the argument to `\num`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[group-minimum-digits=4,group-separator={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_wordcount.txt}
1234
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\numinput}{O{}m}
 {
  \file_get:nnN { #2 } { } \l_tmpa_tl
  \num[#1]{\l_tmpa_tl}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\numinput{\jobname_wordcount.txt} words

\numinput[group-separator={\,}]{\jobname_wordcount.txt} words

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without `expl3` you can use `catchfile` to the same purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[group-minimum-digits=4,group-separator={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_wordcount.txt}
1234
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\numinput}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\numinput@text}{#2}{}%
  \num[#1]{\numinput@text}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\numinput{\jobname_wordcount.txt} words

\numinput[group-separator={\,}]{\jobname_wordcount.txt} words

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you make a mistake when pasting the first chunk of code? It seems to me that the two solutions are the same, both using the `catchfile` package. There's nothing on `expl3` beside your mention of it.

Comment: @bongbang Fixed.

Comment: I think the syntax of the `l3file` package has changed and the relevant command should be `\ior_str_get:NN`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht No, that's for saving the input in the form of a `str`. Not much difference, in the particular case, though.

Comment: Ah, you are right. It still works. Sorry, my bad! The error I got was due to something else obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Some day in the future (might be near) the `functional` package will support optional argument and wrapper for `file_get`, and you can use that.

For now, you can workaround by defining yet another wrapper layer.

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{functional}
\usepackage[group-minimum-digits=4,group-separator={,}]{siunitx}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname_wordcount.txt}
1234
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\PrgNewFunction \fileGet {m} {
 \file_get:nnN { #1 } { } \gResultTl
}

\PrgNewFunction \numWrapperInner {mm} {
 \num[#1]{#2}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\numWrapper}{O{}m}
{
 \numWrapperInner{#1}{#2}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\numWrapper{1234} words  % use normally

\numWrapper{\fileGet{\jobname_wordcount.txt}} words  % use with fileGet function

\numWrapper[group-separator={\,}]{\fileGet{\jobname_wordcount.txt}} words  % and optional argument

\end{document}
```

(remark, the same principle can be used for other argument types/argument preprocessor etc. as well.)