# How can I include comma separator in Latex word count?

Tags: macros, overleaf, word-count, number

I have a word count command in Latex that works well, based on the code [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Is_there_a_way_to_run_a_word_count_that_doesn%27t_include_LaTeX_commands%3F#Using_the_%5Cimport_command_with_texcount). However, I want the output number to be comma separated for thousands (e.g., 1,000 instead of 1000). I have tried using `\numprint` and `\siunitx` but they give me errors, presumably because they can only be applied to a number and not a command. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\quickwordcount}[1]{%
  \immediate\write18{texcount -0 -sum -merge -q #1.tex > #1-words.sum}%
  \input{#1-words.sum}%
}

\begin{document}

There are \quickwordcount{main}words in this document.

\end{document}
```

Of course, in this example there are only 6 words, but I didn't want to add 1,000 words just to show that it says "1000". How can I show the output with comma separators for thousands?

Comment: @JasperHabicht No, sorry. It works to use `\usepackage{siunitx}` and then `\num[group-separator={,}]{12345}`, which gives "12,345". But `\num[group-separator={,}]{\quickwordcount{main}}` gives an error.

Comment: Sorry, I first thought that the [linked solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645111/47927) did not work anymore due to a syntax change, but this is actually not true. It does work. See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be able to use a solution as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/645104/47927):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \quickwordcount } { O{} m } {
    \immediate\write18{texcount ~ -0 ~ -sum ~ -merge ~ -q ~ #2.tex ~ > ~ #2-words.sum}
    \file_get:nnN { #2-words.sum } { } \l_tmpa_tl
    \num[#1]{ \l_tmpa_tl }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

There are \quickwordcount[group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4]{main} words in this document.

\end{document}
```

The following solution should also work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \quickwordcount } { O{} m } {
    \immediate\write18{texcount ~ -0 ~ -sum ~ -merge ~ -q ~ #2.tex ~ > ~ #2-words.sum}
    \ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior { #2-words.sum }
    \ior_str_get:NN \g_tmpa_ior \l_tmpa_tl
    \num[#1]{ \l_tmpa_tl }
    \ior_close:N \g_tmpa_ior
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

There are \quickwordcount[group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits=4]{main} words in this document.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you would not count words generated with something like `\lipsum`, because `texcount` is not able to expand TeX macros.